# C++: How do I optimize out an empty data member from a standard layout class template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, layout

Can I have a standard layout instance of a class template with an optional non-static data member? Being "optional" means that the data member in question *must not* be present in certain instances of the template class.

That is, given:

```
template <typename T>
struct Dependent
{
    T      m_defaultValue;
};

template <>
struct Dependent<double>
{
};

template <typename T>
struct MyData
{
    T*              m_data;
    Dependent<T>    m_optional;

    T LotsOfAccessorMethods() const;
};
```

I want the layout of `MyData<int>` to be equivalent to `struct { int* x; int y; }`.

And I want the layout of `MyData<double>` to be equivalent to `struct { double* x; }`.

The problem here is that the solution must comply with the following key restrictions:

1. **MyData<> must meet the requirements for standard layout class**. Which means that all data members should be located in one class. It is impossible to refactor optional data member(s) to a base class.
2. **MyData<> must not be specialized**, not even partially. In real task it has quite some methods and fields, and repeating them in all specializations would ruin the whole point of having a generic template.

---

Background:

I wish to communicate a lot of special container structures to a DLL/SO which is out of my control. The latter means that I should assume that DLL could have been written is some other language, or perhaps just built with another compiler. This looks like a job for Standard Layout structures.

Those container structures have *very similar* set of data members and member functions, so it would be a shame (and a maintenance nightmare) not to merge them all to a class template.

However, *some* of those containers must have extra data members (tag ids, special values, etc). Hence the question.

Comment: [attribute no_unique_address](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) might help in C++20.

Comment: @Jarod42: That doesn't remove the datamember does it?

Comment: @MikeMB: No guaranty (EBO is also optional), but `sizeof(MyData<double>)` might be equal to `sizeof(double*)`.

Comment: @Jarod42: I doubt that works if `T` (in this case double*) has non-zero size. At least all examples I've seen so far are about optimizing away empty members, so you don't have to go through EBO.

Comment: @MikeMB, I'm not after optimizing `T*`, I wish to optimize `Dependent<T>` which is specialized empty for certain cases. Anyway, this would be a solution for years to come, not for me today.

Comment: You can put `LotsOfAccessorMethods` in a base class (which uses CRTP), and specialize MyData, which derives from that base class. This way there is no need to repeat `LotsOfAccessorMethods`.

Comment: `It is impossible to refactor optional data member(s) to a base class` - Why do you have this restriction? A public inheritance from Dependent<T> can potentially solve your problem, if the set of exceptions is small.

Comment: @BennyK: because I want `MyData` to be a standard layout class, and it would not qualify as a standard layout class if its base class have data members too.

Comment: @IgorG: I didn't imply anything else. It was Jarod's suggestion and I'm just stating that I don't think `attribute no_unique_address` (which would have to be applied to the "vanishing" member) will achieve what he hopes.

Comment: @IgorG if all you want is for it to be a standard layout class, you can an have a base class with non static data members, if the derived class has no data members. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
struct MyData {
    struct general_impl { T* m_data; T optional; };
    struct double_impl  { T* m_data; };

    using data_type = typename std::conditional<
        std::is_same<T, double>::value,
        double_impl,
        general_impl>::type;

    data_type data;

    T LotsOfAccessorMethods() const;
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate to explain how your suggestion fits OP's requirements?

Comment: I would think it pretty obvious, unless I misunderstand something. What requirement are you having trouble with? Note - answer was eddited slightly.

Comment: That looks promising! Thank you. Let me see if the real task can stand an extra `data.` token when accessing its data members. Only I'd replace that `is_same<T, double>` test with 'is_empty<Dependent<T>>'. It would be more generic.

Comment: @IgorG If not, could you inherit from that `std::conditional<...>::type`?